# C# - Force Excel to ReCalc before Save

Tags: c#, excel

Good Morning Overflow-ers!

I have been writing an agent which will open an Excel file, modify two cells and then save the workbook as well as a copy of this workbook.

What I really need is for just before the save, my agent to force a recalc on the whole workbook, so that all of my queries (which are in formula bars due to an inhouse add-in) re-run and get the latest values from an SQL Database.

If anyone could make any suggestions on this, that would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, just `xlApp.Calculate()` should do the trick, based on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet.calculate.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kseswtc.aspx

Comment: I appreciate the response but that's largely useless to me, I'm working on a template which is lots of tables with values, and in the formula bars for those cells are SQL queries - I basically need to 'refresh' the whole workbook.

Comment: Please include actual text rather than just a link. Your answer should be useful even if MSDN breaks the link.