# Excel Interop. Cell changes do not affect dependent formulas

Tags: c#, date, excel-interop

My prorgam adds one new line in Excel document

```
sheetHist.Rows[2].Insert();
```

and then fills it with prices. The first column contains date:

```
sheetHist.Cells[2, 1].Value= DateTime.Now.ToString().Substring(0, 10);
```

There's another sheet (not edited by the program) where I placed formulas like

```
=AVERAGEIFS('List1'!B:B;'List1'!$A:$A;">=01.10.2016";'List1'!$A:$A;"<=31.12.2016")
```

to count avg quarter values (including current quarter).

Everything pastes on the List1 correctly. The problem is when I open the file manually formulas on the List2 ignore the pasted row until I double-click the cell with date (List1!A2) and press Enter without changing anything. It somehow starts formulas recalculation.

What can I do (programmatically, without opening the file manually) to make this recalculation happen?

P.S. "Calculation Options" are set "Auto" in Excel settings.
Column "A" on the List1 already has a date format.

Comment: Are you looking for [recalc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816711/c-sharp-force-excel-to-recalc-before-save) ?

Comment: _There's another page_ Yes, I meant Sheet. app.Calculate() does not help. There's something strange with cell List1!A2, I think Excel does not perceive it as date format until I enter this particular cell

Comment: What I already tried is to paste formula in A2: sheetHist.Cells[2, 1].Formula = "=\"" + DateTime.Now.ToString().Substring(0, 10) + "\""; and it didn't change anything